# how to set listview in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have four listviews saved in a row of a table with a header row.
On selection of item from ist listview, items of 2nd listview are displayed, then on its selection of item , values of 3rd listview are displayed accordingly for 4th listview.
These values differ according to selection.

At present i am selecting first value by default. It is working fine.

But, as it is in a row, i am using horizontal scroll layout for it.

I need to show only one listView at a time, and upon selection of its element next listview should be displayed.

Plz help guyz..

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/primCat"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secCatTV"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/secCat"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testNameTV"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/test"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/advTestTV"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/advTst"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/primaryCategories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
            </ListView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/secondaryCategories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
            </ListView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/testsList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
            </ListView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/selectedTestList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you mean:
1-Select item1 from List1. 2- List1 Gone and List2 shown accordingly selected item1. 3- On selecting item2 from list2, list2 gone and List3 shown.????

Comment: exactly i mean this, but after showing list 2 , i should be able to go back to list 1 to change my choice

Comment: i have answered your question.Please check it and if it solve your problem,accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

You have to use ListAdapters for each listView. OnItemSelect method of first listView, set adapter of second ListView and so on.

Edit:
Test/Sample code is here:

```
private String[] data = { "imran_1664@yahoo.com", "switch2itech@gmail.com" };
    private String[] data2 = { "Lahore", "Karachi", "Islamabad" };
    private ListView listView1, listView2, listView3, listView4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        listView3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3);
        listView4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list4);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        listView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView3.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView4.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        data2);
                listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Enjoy...:)

Comment: There's no need to set the `Adapter` on the next `ListView`s if they are going to change in the `onItemClick`. Just set them there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `ListView`s `visibility` as either `gone` or `invisible`, whichever works best for you, then change it in your `onItemClickListener` of each preceding `ListView`

```
     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/secondaryCategories"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" >   <!-- here -->
```

then in your `onItemClick()`

```
public void onItemClick(...)
{
    listView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // other code
}
```

If I am misunderstanding what you want then please elaborate.

Comment: In that case, i'll not be able to back to previous listView and change my choice

Comment: i think it is possible with horizontal scroll only, but is it possible to show only one listview at a time on screen and rest are on its right and left accordingly and not visible on screen, but they will come if i scroll right or left